# Looping over javascript object looking for key and value - not getting results correctly

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, node.js, object

My data looks like this

```
var obj = { QuestionId: 97,
   SortOrder: { '9': '1' },
   directive: { '1': false, '2': false, '9': true },
   data: { '1': '', '2': '', '9': 'adfaf' } 
}
```

in a loop,  i want to check if  the directive key had a value of true

Expected print out

```
directive key 9 : true
SortOrder key 9 " 1
data key 9 = 'adfaf'
```

Notice that `9` is the only that I care about.

I realize that the `SortOrder` only has 1 key/value pair   - I don't know why that is, but that is going to be a common thing i'm dealing with.

I was trying single loop,  but then a nested loop like this,  but it is not right

```
for (var d in obj) {
    if (d === "directive") {
        for (var prop in obj[d]) {

            if (obj[d][prop] == true) {

            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "it is not right" — That's a very vague problem statement. Do you mean that "nothing is output"? Since you have no code that would make any anyout, that isn't surprising.

Comment: if(obj.directive["9"]) alert("heureka");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could iterate the keys of `obj.directive` and if the value is truthy, then print the values, for the other properties.

```js
var obj = { QuestionId: 97, SortOrder: { 9: '1' }, directive: { 1: false, 2: false, 9: true }, data: { 1: '', 2: '', 9: 'adfaf' } };

Object.keys(obj.directive).forEach(function (k) {
    if (obj.directive[k]) {
        ['directive', 'SortOrder', 'data'].forEach(function (kk) {
            console.log(kk + ' key ' + k + ': ' + obj[kk][k]);
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var obj = { QuestionId: 97,
            SortOrder: { '9': '1' },
            directive: { '1': false, '2': false, '9': true },
            data: { '1': '', '2': '', '9': 'adfaf' } 
          };

if(obj.hasOwnProperty('directive'))
{
    var sortResult = {};
    var dataResult = {};
    var dirResult = Object.keys(obj['directive'])[Object.values(obj['directive']).indexOf(true)];

    if(dirResult){
       sortResult[dirResult] = obj['SortOrder'][dirResult];
       dataResult[dirResult] = obj['data'][dirResult];

       console.log('directive result', dirResult);
       console.log('sortOrder result', sortResult);
       console.log('dara result', dataResult);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

by `obj.directive` . you already have this
`{ '1': false, '2': false, '9': true }`
so `if(obj.directive['9'])` will give you `true`

if you want to do an iteration

```
var x =obj.directive
for (var key in x) {
  if (x.hasOwnProperty(key)) {

     if(x[key])
     {
        //do anything
     }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var obj = { QuestionId: 97,
   SortOrder: { '9': '1' },
   directive: { '1': false, '2': false, '9': true },
   data: { '1': '', '2': '', '9': 'adfaf' } 
}

if (obj && obj.directive) {
  for(x in obj.directive) {
    if (obj.directive[x] === true) {
      console.log('result:', x);
      break;
    }
  }
}
```